# Java FXML - null pointer exception when trying to load new scene

Tags: java, fxml

I am trying to create a function for a button in my FXML, that will put a new scene on the stage.

I have been doing this in my code a few times and it has worked successfully, I copied my code over and it doesn't work, so I'm guessing the issue could be with my directory set-up?

Some insight would be massively appriciated

This is my code where I am trying to change scene:

```
@FXML Button viewFixtureAndResult;

    @FXML
    public void resultsAndFixturesScreen() throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/viewers/fixturesAndResults.fxml"));
        Stage window = (Stage)viewFixtureAndResult.getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(new Scene(root,1000,600));
    }
```

And this is my file set up:

[image]

And my errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at adminView.AdminController.resultsAndFixturesScreen(AdminController.java:115)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: Your stack trace showing /viewers/fixturesAndResults.fxml is not found. Check your resourses folder.

Comment: But if I remove the function it works fine